# How to create a submenu programmatically for Google Glass GDK?

Tags: java, android, google-glass, submenu, voice-recognition

How can I create a Submenu for Google Glass dynamically in Code? I want to select an User with Voice Commands like “Select User” -> “Ben”. The User-Data is loaded from a DB, so an XML menu isn't possible.
This example works for navigation with swipe gestures:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.clear(); 
    SubMenu sbm = menu.addSubMenu(Menu.NONE, 1, menu.NONE, "Select User");
    sbm.add(Menu.NONE, 2, menu.NONE, "Ben");
    sbm.add(Menu.NONE, 3, menu.NONE, "Ted");
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Now I want to use the same with voice commands in the:

```
@Override
public boolean onPreparePanel(int featureId, View view, Menu menu) {
    menu.clear(); 
    SubMenu sbm = menu.addSubMenu(Menu.NONE, 1, menu.NONE, "Select User");
    sbm.add(Menu.NONE, 2, menu.NONE, "Ben");
    sbm.add(Menu.NONE, 3, menu.NONE, "Ted");
    return super.onPreparePanel(featureId, view, menu);
}
```

But the Glass didn’t recognize the voice commands. I hope anyone knows an solution and how can I catch the result? Because the following listing doesn't work for this solution.

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    if (featureId == WindowUtils.FEATURE_VOICE_COMMANDS || featureId == Window.FEATURE_OPTIONS_PANEL) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 1:
        ...
```

many thanks in advance for any solution!

Answer (score 0):

This works fine if I put similar code in `onCreatePanelMenu()`. Since you are using [unlisted voice commands](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/voice#unlisted_commands), did you include the following permission in your manifest?

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.glass.permission.DEVELOPMENT"/>
```